# Why is a user getting "secure connection failed" in Firefox for Mac?

Tags: apache, firefox, ssl-certificate

One of our users is having trouble getting past the cart page. She is using Firefox 38.0.5 on a Mac and she said that she checked for updates and it said it was up to date.

When she clicks the "continue to checkout button", she gets the error below.
[image: Error message]

I have tried to reproduce this issue on our macs here using Firefox as well as Windows (Firefox, Safari, Chrome, IE), but I cannot reproduce the issue.

The whole site is using https.

- Signature algorithm: sha256RSA
- Issuer - Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
- Valid from: ‎Monday, ‎April ‎13, ‎2015 11:03:39
- Valid to: ‎Friday, ‎May ‎25, ‎2018 08:53:55

[image]

Encryption details on FF:
[image]

Server configuration:

```
# apache2ctl -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.10 (Linux/SUSE)
Server built:   Feb 23 2009 21:08:14

# openssl version -a
OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
built on: Sat Feb 21 02:45:26 UTC 2009
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) md2(int) rc4(ptr,int) des(idx,cisc,4,long) blowfish(idx)
compiler: gcc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DL_ENDIAN -DNO_ASM -DMD32_REG_T=int -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -DTERMIO -Wall -fstack-protector -fprofile-use
OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/ssl"
```

Comment: I ran into this issue when doing some fancy `RedirectMatch`es, `RewriteCond`s, and `RewriteRule`s. Perhaps Firefox is getting confused with redirection?